# Obtain TFS GIT Commit Details From TFS Work Item Artifact Link

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to leverage TFS or TS REST api to obtain details for a GIT commit by leveraging the work item commit "ArtifiactLink" url?

Answer (score 4):

So you want to get detail commit information based on a work item artifacts link (while the artifact link type contains commit).

You can achieve that with two REST API, detail steps as below:

#### 1.   [Get the work item with full expanded](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#fully-expanded)

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version1.0&$expand=all
```

For TFS2015, the format looks like:

```
GET http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={id}&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```

For VSTS, the format looks like:

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=7&$expand=all&api-version=1.0
```

#### 2.   Get commit(s) and related repo(s) linked in the above work item

Search in the response of the step1 REST API, get the part which `rel` is `ArtifactLink` and the `url` start with `vstfs:///Git/Commit`. The URL format is

```
vstfs:///Git/Commit/{project ID}%2F{repo ID}%2F{commit ID}
```

Such as part of the REST API response as:

```
{
   "rel": "ArtifactLink",
   "url": "vstfs:///Git/Commit/b959f22b-eeb7-40dc-b37e-986377eaa86f%2F4cfde261-fec3-451c-9d41-a400ba816110%2Fb3c3c5b8718f403402be770cb3b5912df7c64dd6",
   "attributes": {
      "authorizedDate": "2017-09-26T03:14:03.98Z",
      "id": 92,
      "resourceCreatedDate": "2017-09-26T03:14:03.98Z",
      "resourceModifiedDate": "2017-09-26T03:14:03.98Z",
      "revisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "name": "Fixed in Commit"
    }
}
```

The project ID is `b959f22b-eeb7-40dc-b37e-986377eaa86f`, the repo ID is `2F4cfde261-fec3-451c-9d41-a400ba816110` and the commit ID is `b3c3c5b8718f403402be770cb3b5912df7c64dd6`.

#### 3.   Get commit(s) details

Use the project ID, repo ID and commit ID you get in step2 to [get a single commit](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#just-the-commit):

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project ID}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo ID}/commits/{commit ID}?api-version={version}
```

For TFS 2015, the format looks like:

```
GET http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project ID}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo ID}/commits/{commit ID}?api-version=1.0
```

For VSTS, the format looks like:

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project ID}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo ID}/commits/{commit ID}?api-version=1.0
```