# Is there an API call to get VSTS work item given its branch name

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a powershell script as part of my VSTS build definition. In here, I have access to the branch name that triggered the build.

Each branch belongs to an associated work item (done via the work item's "Create a new branch" link).

**Question**: How do I get the work item ID in my script?

I thought one place to start might be WIQL but was unable to locate the field name (if there even is one) corresponding to the work item's branch:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/work-item-field

**Edit 1**: Based on answer by @starian chen-MSFT

When I run the following dynamic query:

`$body = @{query = "Select [System.Id], [System.AssignedTo] From WorkItemLinks WHERE Source.[System.TeamProject] = 'MyProj' and (Source.[System.State] = 'New' OR Source.[System.State] = 'Active') and Source.[System.ExternalLinkCount] > 0"}`

At the uri:

`$uri = "https://MyAccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0"`

I get the following in the returned response:

```
"workItemRelations":  [
  {
    "rel":  null,
    "source":  null,
    "target":  "@{id=11; url=https://MyProj.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/11}"
  },
  {
    "rel":  "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
    "source":  "@{id=11; url=https://MyProj.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/11}",
    "target":  "@{id=3; url=https://MyProj.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/3}"
  }
]
```

**Question**: Only work item with ID 11 has an external link, so don't know how to stop `Hierarchy-Forward` entries from getting in there.
Also, how do I get the `AssignedTo` value in there? It doesn't seem to be showing up in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t get the work item with branch name through the Query directly.

You can add **tags** with that branch name, then it’s easy to get that work item with branch name.

Another way is that:

1. Retrieve work items through Query REST API: [Run a stored query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#run-a-stored-query). (Include this filter to query: `External Link Count  >=   1`)
2. Retrieve those work items with links: [With links and attachments](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments)
3. Check which work item contains current branch link.

Update:

Simple code to get branch name:

```
$branchUrl="vstfs:///Git/Ref/b8ee4b6d-d5a8-4e3d-a7f8-f2da9713a830%2Fed10a5f5-f558-4dc2-bce9-dee7bfe617b0%2FGBworkitembranch"
$branchName=$branchUrl.Split("%2F")[-1]
$branchName=$branchName.Substring(2,$branchName.Length-2)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Please see Edit 1.

Comment: Using Flat list of work items query, such as `select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = 'xxx' and ([System.State] = 'New' or [System.State] = 'Active') and [System.ExternalLinkCount] > 0 order by [System.Id]`

Comment: The result contains workitems list, then you need to retrieve the details of them through Work Items REST API (step2)

Comment: On other hand, I'd suggest asking separate questions in new forum threads instead of edit current thread. Thus, forum readers may recognize questions and answers easily.

Comment: So is it just the addition of 'order by' that makes the list flat?

Comment: No, `from WorkItems`

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that. I see. Thanks. Will try this and if it works, will be happy to accept answer.

Comment: Ok, so I'm making progress. I ran this `https://MyAccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/<a_work_item_id>?$expand=all&api-version=2.0` and for `$response.relations.url`, I get `"url": "vstfs:///Git/Ref/<some_big_hex_string>%2FGBMyBranch"`. The environment variable I access in my powershell script is `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` which just returns `MyBranch`. So I can't really compare this to the ArtifactLink url under relations. Could you please elaborate a bit more on your step 3.

Comment: As it turns out, that long hex string is actually the <project_id>%2f<repo_id>. So `$response.relations.url` is vstfs:///Git/Ref/<project_id>%2f<repo_id>%2fGB<my_branch_name>. I know the '%2f' corresponds to forward slashes. Don't know what the 'GB' is. Really don't want to resort to regexing. Hoping there is a cleaner API call...

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the ArtifactLink url will always be of the format vstfs:///Git/Ref/<project id>%2f<repo id>%2fGB<branch name> ? (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414317/obtain-tfs-git-commit-details-from-tfs-work-item-artifact-link/) What is that 'GB' bit anyway?

Comment: According to that thread, ArtifactLink url has a different format altogether.

Comment: It's safe. Regarding that thread, it is commit artifactlink url instead of branch.